# Replace exact string in bash

Tags: string, bash, sed

I have a list that looks like this:

```
server
server.apple.com
server.apple.com
server
server.apple.com
```

Now, I would like to add ".apple.com" to the lines that says just "server". I've tried sed with:

```
sed -e 's/\bserver\b/server.apple.com/g'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
sed 's/^server$/server.apple.com/g'
```

`^` means start of line and `$` means end of the line.

You also don't need the `-e` argument, as this is just basic regex.

If you want case insensitive search for `server` (also match `SERVER` and `SErvEr`) you can use the `I` function, however it is not supported by various versions of `sed`:

```
sed 's/^server$/server.apple.com/Ig'
```

If you don't have a `sed` version that supports `I` you can use:

```
sed 's/^[Ss][Ee][Rr][Vv][Ee][Rr]$/server.apple.com/g'
```

Comment: Thanks! So obvious when you see it :)

Comment: And if I want to ignore case? ("server" is sometimes "SERVER" or "Server" in the list)

Comment: Great! Thanks very much! Just to make everything even more dynamic, is there a regex that can match anything that doesn't have a domain, like: I want to match every line that doesn't end with apple.com or any of the ten sub.apple.com subdomains, not just specific server names? And make this case insensitive?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/^server$/server.apple.com/g' inputfile
```

`^` means the beggining of a line and `$` the end, therefore this matches only those lines, that have no additional text.

Comment: 'sentence' might not be the best word to describe it.